# Javascript - get object property value NOT reference

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have created a module that I use to write to a global array like so:

```
class SomeLibrary {

  constructor( product ) {
    if (typeof window.globalArray === 'undefined'){
        window.globalArray = [];
    }
    this._someVal = 0;
  }
  .
  .
  .
  addToGlobalArray( obj ) {
    obj.someVal = this._someVal;
    window.globalArray.push( obj );
    this._someVal++
  }
  .
  .
  .
  .
}

let someLib = new SomeLibrary();
someLib.addToGlobalArray({test: 'hello'})
someLib.addToGlobalArray({test: 'hello again'});
```

And want my 'globalArray's 'someVal' to use the current **value** of _someVal from the module *not the reference* for the result to look like:

```
//I want this outcome    
[
    {test: 'hello', someVal: 0},
    {test: 'hello again', someVal: 1}
]
```

***Not (as it currently operates)***

```
//I don't want this outcome    
[
    {test: 'hello', someVal: 1}, //someVal here is 1 as it is a reference to the current value of _someVal in the module
    {test: 'hello again', someVal: 1}
]
```

What do I need to do to pass the value and not the reference into the global Object?

(I don't have access to jQuery or Underscore)

Answer (score 1):

Your code already works the way you say you want it to.

By definition, the property being added to the object being added to the global array is added by **value** (its value at that precise moment in time), not by reference; indeed, there is no way to do that in JS other than via things like "getters" or "proxies".

I suspect you are actually running something like the following code:

```
var object = {test: "hello"};
someLib.addToGlobalArray(object})

object.test = "hello again"; 
someLib.addToGlobalArray(object);
```

This would result in the single object `{test: "hello again", someVal: 1}` occupying both the first and second position in the global array. That fact that `someVal` has the same value of 1 in both `globalArray[0]` and `globalArray[1]` has nothing to do with some notion of it being set by reference; it is just because it's **the same object** in both slots.

Comment: …with the exception of `{get someVal() { return self._someVal; }}`

Comment: @Bergi Thanks, fixed up the answer to reflect that.